# Using tikzexternalize and LuaLaTeX leads to display problems in viewer

Tags: tikz-pgf, viewers, tikz-external

I am using the following code

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzset{external/system call={lualatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\hspace*{.0\linewidth}\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\input{picture.tex}}
\end{center}  
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

containing this rather long TikZ picture as `picture.tex`. Looks ugly, but I created the original image using Inkscape and afterwards used an export tool to convert it to TikZ.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt, x=0.8pt,yscale=-1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
\begin{scope}[shift={(7471.7426,2551.8505)}]% layer1
\begin{scope}% g5193
\begin{scope}% g5148
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.17388,0.0,0.0,1.17388,(-7186.7124,-2753.3928)}}]% g3934
    \begin{scope}% g3927
      % path15-7
      \path[draw=black,miter limit=4.00,line width=3.200pt] (596.8110,270.9895) --
        (575.1970,284.3355) .. controls (571.3210,286.7295) and (566.3920,287.7725) ..
        (561.8570,287.3165) -- (510.6700,282.1515)(593.0770,269.1245) --
        (573.5910,281.0345) .. controls (570.3660,283.0065) and (566.3080,284.0135) ..
        (562.5460,283.6295) -- (513.1500,278.5855) .. controls (511.6520,277.1425) and
        (509.8060,275.7835) .. (507.6100,274.5565);

      % path19-4
      \path[draw=black,miter limit=4.00,line width=3.200pt] (61.1280,177.3815) --
        (43.7980,302.6695)(52.5390,303.9275) .. controls (63.9900,300.9715) and
        (80.5510,301.8085) .. (99.4350,304.3755);

      % path21-0
      \path[draw=black,miter limit=4.00,line width=3.200pt] (497.3920,247.1955) ..
        controls (500.1060,246.7475) and (502.8180,246.2995) .. (505.5300,245.8555) ..
        controls (519.3440,243.5885) and (537.0710,243.3185) .. (556.7760,250.0855) ..
        controls (570.2670,254.7175) and (583.4920,262.0625) .. (594.5470,268.6015) ..
        controls (597.1920,270.1635) and (598.1890,270.5795) .. (601.2070,271.0925) ..
        controls (630.8390,276.1565) and (662.9960,282.5555) .. (689.1340,298.2395) ..
        controls (698.0900,303.6095) and (702.1660,313.0465) .. (689.3220,318.3635) ..
        controls (657.0540,331.7185) and (613.7270,336.4585) .. (579.4820,338.3655) ..
        controls (552.0290,339.8885) and (520.6710,339.1255) .. (485.6280,333.8435) ..
        controls (458.9970,329.8335) and (432.5170,323.9235) .. (405.9420,319.5745) ..
        controls (385.0670,316.1575) and (363.6860,314.5305) .. (342.6410,312.4985) ..
        controls (318.7300,310.1855) and (294.9960,308.7555) .. (271.0340,307.3185) ..
        controls (241.6040,305.5565) and (212.0980,305.3605) .. (182.6410,304.1105) ..
        controls (155.6020,302.9665) and (114.4990,303.2895) .. (106.1600,304.4455) ..
        controls (99.6290,305.3475) and (93.7130,308.4365) .. (87.2050,309.4915) ..
        controls (76.7000,311.1935) and (65.8180,310.1085) .. (55.1490,307.3455) ..
        controls (45.5700,304.8675) and (2.5530,291.8745) .. (7.8310,273.6985) --
        (35.4760,178.4945) .. controls (45.3490,175.4225) and (89.2910,167.4655) ..
        (91.9300,182.9515) -- (103.2140,249.1855) .. controls (103.7110,252.1065) and
        (104.4220,256.6135) .. (105.6430,259.5085) .. controls (113.0950,260.7115) and
        (115.0920,264.0495) .. (108.9230,265.5235) .. controls (109.6000,266.8605) and
        (110.0520,267.5555) .. (110.5310,268.1385) -- (110.6940,268.3365) .. controls
        (113.9480,272.2955) and (118.3380,274.5435) .. (125.0570,274.1895) .. controls
        (223.6570,268.9695) and (322.1850,262.4185) .. (420.7750,256.9965) .. controls
        (429.4630,256.5175) and (438.1990,255.6695) .. (446.9450,254.6485) --
        (456.3310,247.7535) .. controls (457.3500,247.0075) and (457.8290,245.8835) ..
        (458.1350,244.9545) .. controls (480.8850,239.9015) and (495.4440,242.1085) ..
        (496.9950,246.1985) -- (497.3870,247.2265);

      % path25-9
      \path[draw=black,miter limit=4.00,line width=3.200pt] (446.9870,254.6805) --
        (430.3170,267.0385) -- (408.2080,289.5885) .. controls (411.5730,289.3365) and
        (414.9750,289.0825) .. (418.3470,288.9045) .. controls (421.7950,288.7175) and
        (425.2040,288.5015) .. (428.6580,288.4995) .. controls (432.0950,288.4965) and
        (435.5350,288.6445) .. (438.9680,288.8165) .. controls (442.4060,288.9885) and
        (445.8300,289.3135) .. (449.2660,289.5265) .. controls (452.7490,289.7405) and
        (456.2340,290.0175) .. (459.7240,290.0925) .. controls (463.1480,290.1705) and
        (466.5790,290.1245) .. (470.0020,289.9805) .. controls (473.4030,289.8355) and
        (476.8010,289.5455) .. (480.1900,289.2185) .. controls (483.5970,288.8915) and
        (487.0030,288.5215) .. (490.3870,288.0255) .. controls (493.7880,287.5235) and
        (497.2020,286.9815) .. (500.5410,286.2235) .. controls (504.0800,285.4165) and
        (510.6800,283.9415) .. (510.5080,281.9565) .. controls (510.4960,281.8025) and
        (510.4560,281.6435) .. (510.3960,281.4775) -- (497.3930,247.2225);

      % path29-4
      \path[draw=black,miter limit=4.00,line width=3.200pt] (49.5890,262.7865) --
        (65.8180,260.8505) .. controls (86.7740,258.3515) and (112.4220,258.8725) ..
        (112.4220,262.7865) .. controls (112.4220,266.7015) and (86.7750,267.2225) ..
        (65.8180,264.7225) -- cycle;

    \end{scope}
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}% g4576
    % path3925
    \path[color=black,fill=black,line width=10.803pt] (-5977.0000,-2398.4062) ..
      controls (-6179.8869,-2397.1578) and (-6293.3830,-2397.5938) ..
      (-6344.9688,-2397.5938) -- (-6344.9688,-2384.0938) .. controls
      (-6293.4557,-2384.0938) and (-6179.8426,-2383.6575) .. (-5976.9062,-2384.9062)
      .. controls (-5956.4512,-2385.0321) and (-5936.4877,-2374.0238) ..
      (-5916.2188,-2351.5312) .. controls (-5895.9498,-2329.0387) and
      (-5875.8963,-2295.3171) .. (-5856.2812,-2252.2188) .. controls
      (-5817.0511,-2166.0220) and (-5779.3691,-2042.4019) .. (-5740.9062,-1895.1562)
      .. controls (-5678.1494,-1654.9070) and (-5613.2450,-1351.6677) ..
      (-5534.9062,-1043.6875) .. controls (-5431.6615,-637.7916) and
      (-5305.2073,-223.6769) .. (-5128.7188,66.3750) .. controls
      (-5047.6660,199.5819) and (-4899.4184,274.3444) .. (-4748.2500,316.0000) ..
      controls (-4597.0816,357.6556) and (-4442.5775,366.2813) ..
      (-4347.2812,366.2813) -- (-4347.2812,352.7813) .. controls
      (-4441.7572,352.7813) and (-4595.3338,344.1243) .. (-4744.6875,302.9688) ..
      controls (-4894.0412,261.8132) and (-5038.7449,188.2410) ..
      (-5117.1562,59.3750) .. controls (-5292.1639,-228.2429) and
      (-5418.6769,-641.5645) .. (-5521.8125,-1047.0312) .. controls
      (-5600.0684,-1354.6858) and (-5664.9602,-1657.8280) .. (-5727.8438,-1898.5625)
      .. controls (-5766.3843,-2046.1055) and (-5804.1074,-2170.1603) ..
      (-5844.0000,-2257.8125) .. controls (-5863.9463,-2301.6386) and
      (-5884.4064,-2336.3918) .. (-5906.1875,-2360.5625) .. controls
      (-5927.9686,-2384.7332) and (-5951.6104,-2398.5625) .. (-5977.0000,-2398.4062)
      -- cycle;

    % path4582
    \path[draw=black,fill=black,even odd rule,line width=5.402pt]
      (-6030.9682,-2391.3358) -- (-6057.8092,-2364.1625) -- (-5963.4504,-2391.7512)
      -- (-6058.1415,-2418.1767) -- (-6030.9682,-2391.3358) -- cycle;

    % path4584
    \path[draw=black,fill=black,even odd rule,line width=5.402pt]
      (-5748.0139,-1949.1198) -- (-5780.9705,-1968.4248) -- (-5730.9494,-1883.7927)
      -- (-5728.7088,-1982.0764) -- (-5748.0139,-1949.1198) -- cycle;

    % path4586
    \path[draw=black,fill=black,even odd rule,line width=5.402pt]
      (-5541.6740,-1097.7085) -- (-5574.5059,-1117.2250) -- (-5525.0296,-1032.2731)
      -- (-5522.1575,-1130.5404) -- (-5541.6740,-1097.7085) -- cycle;

    % path4588
    \path[draw=black,fill=black,even odd rule,line width=5.402pt]
      (-5151.0138,16.7330) -- (-5188.1247,7.6996) -- (-5115.9168,74.4135) --
      (-5141.9804,-20.3779) -- (-5151.0138,16.7330) -- cycle;

    % path4590
    \path[draw=black,fill=black,even odd rule,line width=5.402pt]
      (-4401.2891,359.5360) -- (-4428.2967,386.5436) -- (-4333.7700,359.5360) --
      (-4428.2967,332.5283) -- (-4401.2891,359.5360) -- cycle;

  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.17388,0.0,0.0,1.17388,(794.91163,334.55886)}}]% g3934-8
    \begin{scope}% g3927-2
      % path15-7-45
      \path[draw=black,miter limit=4.00,line width=3.200pt] (596.8110,270.9895) --
        (575.1970,284.3355) .. controls (571.3210,286.7295) and (566.3920,287.7725) ..
        (561.8570,287.3165) -- (510.6700,282.1515)(593.0770,269.1245) --
        (573.5910,281.0345) .. controls (570.3660,283.0065) and (566.3080,284.0135) ..
        (562.5460,283.6295) -- (513.1500,278.5855) .. controls (511.6520,277.1425) and
        (509.8060,275.7835) .. (507.6100,274.5565);

      % path19-4-5
      \path[draw=black,miter limit=4.00,line width=3.200pt] (61.1280,177.3815) --
        (43.7980,302.6695)(52.5390,303.9275) .. controls (63.9900,300.9715) and
        (80.5510,301.8085) .. (99.4350,304.3755);

      % path21-0-1
      \path[draw=black,miter limit=4.00,line width=3.200pt] (497.3920,247.1955) ..
        controls (500.1060,246.7475) and (502.8180,246.2995) .. (505.5300,245.8555) ..
        controls (519.3440,243.5885) and (537.0710,243.3185) .. (556.7760,250.0855) ..
        controls (570.2670,254.7175) and (583.4920,262.0625) .. (594.5470,268.6015) ..
        controls (597.1920,270.1635) and (598.1890,270.5795) .. (601.2070,271.0925) ..
        controls (630.8390,276.1565) and (662.9960,282.5555) .. (689.1340,298.2395) ..
        controls (698.0900,303.6095) and (702.1660,313.0465) .. (689.3220,318.3635) ..
        controls (657.0540,331.7185) and (613.7270,336.4585) .. (579.4820,338.3655) ..
        controls (552.0290,339.8885) and (520.6710,339.1255) .. (485.6280,333.8435) ..
        controls (458.9970,329.8335) and (432.5170,323.9235) .. (405.9420,319.5745) ..
        controls (385.0670,316.1575) and (363.6860,314.5305) .. (342.6410,312.4985) ..
        controls (318.7300,310.1855) and (294.9960,308.7555) .. (271.0340,307.3185) ..
        controls (241.6040,305.5565) and (212.0980,305.3605) .. (182.6410,304.1105) ..
        controls (155.6020,302.9665) and (114.4990,303.2895) .. (106.1600,304.4455) ..
        controls (99.6290,305.3475) and (93.7130,308.4365) .. (87.2050,309.4915) ..
        controls (76.7000,311.1935) and (65.8180,310.1085) .. (55.1490,307.3455) ..
        controls (45.5700,304.8675) and (2.5530,291.8745) .. (7.8310,273.6985) --
        (35.4760,178.4945) .. controls (45.3490,175.4225) and (89.2910,167.4655) ..
        (91.9300,182.9515) -- (103.2140,249.1855) .. controls (103.7110,252.1065) and
        (104.4220,256.6135) .. (105.6430,259.5085) .. controls (113.0950,260.7115) and
        (115.0920,264.0495) .. (108.9230,265.5235) .. controls (109.6000,266.8605) and
        (110.0520,267.5555) .. (110.5310,268.1385) -- (110.6940,268.3365) .. controls
        (113.9480,272.2955) and (118.3380,274.5435) .. (125.0570,274.1895) .. controls
        (223.6570,268.9695) and (322.1850,262.4185) .. (420.7750,256.9965) .. controls
        (429.4630,256.5175) and (438.1990,255.6695) .. (446.9450,254.6485) --
        (456.3310,247.7535) .. controls (457.3500,247.0075) and (457.8290,245.8835) ..
        (458.1350,244.9545) .. controls (480.8850,239.9015) and (495.4440,242.1085) ..
        (496.9950,246.1985) -- (497.3870,247.2265);

      % path25-9-7
      \path[draw=black,miter limit=4.00,line width=3.200pt] (446.9870,254.6805) --
        (430.3170,267.0385) -- (408.2080,289.5885) .. controls (411.5730,289.3365) and
        (414.9750,289.0825) .. (418.3470,288.9045) .. controls (421.7950,288.7175) and
        (425.2040,288.5015) .. (428.6580,288.4995) .. controls (432.0950,288.4965) and
        (435.5350,288.6445) .. (438.9680,288.8165) .. controls (442.4060,288.9885) and
        (445.8300,289.3135) .. (449.2660,289.5265) .. controls (452.7490,289.7405) and
        (456.2340,290.0175) .. (459.7240,290.0925) .. controls (463.1480,290.1705) and
        (466.5790,290.1245) .. (470.0020,289.9805) .. controls (473.4030,289.8355) and
        (476.8010,289.5455) .. (480.1900,289.2185) .. controls (483.5970,288.8915) and
        (487.0030,288.5215) .. (490.3870,288.0255) .. controls (493.7880,287.5235) and
        (497.2020,286.9815) .. (500.5410,286.2235) .. controls (504.0800,285.4165) and
        (510.6800,283.9415) .. (510.5080,281.9565) .. controls (510.4960,281.8025) and
        (510.4560,281.6435) .. (510.3960,281.4775) -- (497.3930,247.2225);

      % path29-4-1
      \path[draw=black,miter limit=4.00,line width=3.200pt] (49.5890,262.7865) --
        (65.8180,260.8505) .. controls (86.7740,258.3515) and (112.4220,258.8725) ..
        (112.4220,262.7865) .. controls (112.4220,266.7015) and (86.7750,267.2225) ..
        (65.8180,264.7225) -- cycle;

    \end{scope}
  \end{scope}
  % path4204
  \path[draw=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,miter limit=4.00,line
    width=13.504pt] (-7471.7354,856.0697) -- (2053.0309,856.0697);

  % path3946
  \path[cm={{0.72139,0.0,0.0,0.8304,(-3559.1797,-2575.6467)}},draw=black,line
    cap=butt,miter limit=4.00,line width=16.000pt]
    (-723.3183,4124.8642)arc(180.013:359.987:185.853);

  % path3948
  \path[draw=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,miter limit=4.00,line
    width=6.192pt] (-3532.8463,853.6449) -- (-3532.8463,649.2598) --
    (-3448.2967,664.5541) -- (-3448.2967,690.9713) -- (-3534.0542,704.8750);

  % path3950
  \path[draw=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,miter limit=4.00,line
    width=6.192pt] (-3468.5953,658.9924) -- (-3468.5953,692.3614);

  % path3952
  \path[draw=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,miter limit=4.00,line
    width=6.192pt] (-3485.9750,657.6021) -- (-3485.9750,695.1422);

  % path3954
  \path[draw=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,miter limit=4.00,line
    width=6.192pt] (-3501.4422,652.0406) -- (-3501.4422,697.9229);

  % path3956
  \path[draw=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,miter limit=4.00,line
    width=6.192pt] (-3516.6744,652.0406) -- (-3516.6744,702.0941);

  % path4244
  \path[draw=black,dash pattern=on 64.82pt off 64.82pt,line join=miter,line
    cap=butt,miter limit=4.00,line width=10.803pt] (-4255.0378,354.7662) --
    (-4255.0378,-714.6359);

  % path4244-1
  \path[draw=black,dash pattern=on 64.82pt off 64.82pt,line join=miter,line
    cap=butt,miter limit=4.00,line width=10.803pt] (251.8578,354.7662) --
    (251.8578,-714.6359);

  \begin{scope}% g4592
    % path4454
    \path[color=black,fill=black,line width=10.803pt] (-4225.2812,-669.2188) --
      (-4225.2812,-655.7188) -- (222.5313,-655.7188) -- (222.5313,-669.2188) --
      (-4225.2812,-669.2188) -- cycle;

    % path4598
    \path[draw=black,fill=black,even odd rule,line width=5.402pt]
      (-4171.2618,-662.4633) -- (-4144.2542,-689.4710) -- (-4238.7809,-662.4633) --
      (-4144.2542,-635.4557) -- (-4171.2618,-662.4633) -- cycle;

    % path4600
    \path[draw=black,fill=black,even odd rule,line width=5.402pt]
      (168.5264,-662.4633) -- (141.5188,-635.4557) -- (236.0455,-662.4633) --
      (141.5188,-689.4710) -- (168.5264,-662.4633) -- cycle;

  \end{scope}
  % text4836
  \path[fill=black] (-2760.2979,-716.64734) node[above right,font=\fontsize{130}{10}\selectfont] (text4836)
    {Messsegment (H = const.)};

  % text4844
  \path[fill=black] (316.43518,312.34344) node[above right,font=\fontsize{130}{10}\selectfont] (text4844) {$V_{min}$ (Abriss)};

  % path5749
  \path[draw=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,miter limit=4.00,line
    width=10.803pt] (-4380.4882,359.4433) -- (284.1386,359.4433);

  \begin{scope}% g4602
    % path5751
    \path[color=black,fill=black,line width=10.803pt] (283.9063,352.6875) --
      (283.3750,366.1875) .. controls (480.5931,373.6510) and (615.0762,502.2643) ..
      (764.5625,607.4375) -- (772.3125,596.4063) .. controls (623.9694,492.0373) and
      (486.7386,360.3635) .. (283.9063,352.6875) -- cycle;

    % path4608
    \path[draw=black,fill=black,even odd rule,line width=5.402pt]
      (724.2578,570.8487) -- (686.6287,577.3965) -- (779.4789,609.7003) --
      (717.7100,533.2196) -- (724.2578,570.8487) -- cycle;

  \end{scope}
  % path3946-1
  \path[cm={{0.55379,0.0,0.0,0.63748,(-3650.7574,-1780.6716)}},draw=black,line
    cap=butt,miter limit=4.00,line width=16.000pt]
    (-723.3183,4124.8642)arc(180.013:359.987:185.853);

\end{scope}
\end{scope}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

As you can see I am using `tikzexternalize` and LuaLaTeX. I have tried this with MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows 7 x64.

The processing run gives me no errors at all, but neither the viewer in TeXWorks nor Adobe Reader are displaying the picture in the final document. The image still seems to be there, because the contained text can still be marked (though invisible). However, the picture is visible using Foxit Reader. Furthermore, the separately generated PDF which is included in the final document shows up just fine with Adobe Reader. The entire problem does not occur when I am not using externalization.

As this problem only occurs with this image, I suppose the error is in the TikZ picture itself.

I already know about the option to skip a single image in the externalization process using

```
\tikzset{external/export next=false}
```

but I still would like to know what is wrong.